# Calculate dimensions of NumPy SVD matrices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dimensions, svd

I've calculated the Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) matrices with NumPy, upon a (22000,400) array, by the command

`u, s, vh = np.linalg.svd(final_array, full_matrices=False)`

I've printed `u`, `s` and `vh`, and it's working fine. Now I'm trying to visualize their dimensions, using:

```
u.shape()
s.shape()
vh.shape()
```

But I keep getting the error:

**TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable**

How could I solve this issue?

Comment: In Numpy, `shape` is a property (which stores a tuple), not a method.  Try `u.shape`.

Comment: When you say "visualize their dimensions", what do you mean, exactly?

Comment: I dont't know how many lines and columns each matrix has, so I need to obtain a result with [numrows, numcolumns] of **u,s** and **vh**

Comment: @ElisaMariaAlves as andrew_reece mentioned, you want to print(u.shape)

Comment: It just worked!! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Numpy, [`shape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html) is a property (which stores a tuple), not a method.  Try `u.shape`.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2])
a.shape # (2,)
```